# Smooth open UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to get smooth edges of Arcs and Curves.

The SKShapeNodes are open UIBezierPaths with a thick line-width, however, jagged edges are noticeable around Arcs and Curves. Changing the flatness doesn't seem to have any effect. Is there a way to smoothen these, or am I going to have to make a closed UIBezierPath with no line-width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to my problem. Instead of using path.addArc(), I now use a function to get as many points as I'd like along an arc and then use path.addLine() to every one of those points. If you want more points for a smoother path, just lower the value of n.

```
func getCirclePoints(centerPoint: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool) -> [CGPoint] {
    let n : CGFloat = clockwise ? -1 : 1
    let points: [CGPoint] = stride(from: startAngle - n, through: endAngle + n, by: n).map {

        let degreesToRadians = CGFloat($0) * .pi / 180

        let x = centerPoint.x + radius * cos(degreesToRadians)
        let y = centerPoint.y + radius * sin(degreesToRadians)

        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    return points
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create closed UIBezierPath with no linewidth 
also
Make it `shouldRasterize = true` and set proper scale `rasterizationScale = 2 * UIScreen.main.scale`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The closed path with no line width makes no difference unfortunately. Where do I set the rasterizationScale? Thanks